# How to FlatMap Option while Preserving When Empty

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type, either

I would like to flatmap option transformations, while having visibility into where the transformation "dropped out" (that is, where a `None` is first returned).

Some sample code:

```
val stringFetcher : DomainObject=>Option[String] = ...

val filterer : String=>Option[String] = ...

val reportFilteredCause: DomainObject => String = do =>
{
   val strOption = stringFetcher(do)
   val filterReasonOption = strOption flatMap filterer
   filterReasonOption.getOrElse("Failed to fetch string representation OR field not filtered")
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to write something like below, where I pass in some reporting string associated with every Option transformation:

```
val stringFetcher : DomainObject=>Option[String] = ...

val filterer : String=>Option[String] = ...

val reportFilteredCause: DomainObject => String = do =>
{
   val strOption : Either[Option[String], String]] = EitherWrapper stringFetcher(do) "Failed to fetch string representation"
   val filterReasonOption = strOption flatMapWrapper filterer "Failed to filter field
   filterReasonOption
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `stringFetcher` and `getStringRepr`? It looks like they do the same thing. Why is one defined but unused while the other is used but undefined?

Comment: `stringFetcher` and `filterer` are just the two operations that I want to apply (in their respective order!) to `DomainObject`. I put `...` in place of a definition - they should both be used and defined

Comment: Re-read my question (and your code). Why is `stringFetcher` defined but never used? Why is `getStringRepr` used in the code but never defined?

Comment: fixed ;) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is an `Either[String,String]` where the left projection is the failure message and the right projection is the result string.

```
val reportFilteredCause :DomainObject => String = { dob :DomainObject =>

  val strOption :Either[String, String] =
    stringFetcher(dob).toRight("Failed to fetch string representation")

  val filterReasonOption :Either[String,String] =
    strOption.flatMap(filterer(_).toRight("Failed to filter field"))

  filterReasonOption.fold(identity,identity)
}
```

The `.toRight()` method transforms an `Option` into an `Either`:

```
Some(x).toRight(y) //x.right
None.toRight(y)    //y.left
```

Although, in truth, it's probably easier and clearer to use `fold()` and `getOrElse()`.

```
val reportFilteredCause :DomainObject => String = {
  stringFetcher(_).fold("Failed to fetch string representation"){
   filterer(_).getOrElse("Failed to filter field")
  }
}
```